# Locking and unlocking rows in sql database from C# winform

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a project where I use a select statement to select a group of records from a sql table, I need to locked the selected records and then update some and move others to another table. Right now I have a select such as this.

```
Select item 
from tableA 
where batchno = 123;
```

I believe I would lock them by writing it like this

```
Select item 
from tableA with (rowlock, readpast)
where batchno = 123;
```

This is basically the select then I do an update on each records in a datagridview and place in another table that contains all that has been added to the record as well as the original fields. When I insert the records into the other table I delete the original records,those not updated, I change the batch number on those that are not updated and need to release the lock.

I use the readpast in order that no records already selected will appear for other useres. I believe that is right.

If this is correct I need to know how to release the records. I am new to C# so please make it clear and be patient.

Comment: Which type of SQL, is this SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the lock is released as soon as the transaction commits or rolbacks